# Use 2 different symbologies on the same feature QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I have data symbolized with different categories 
Each category has a field for different symbology style like the table below. 
Is it possible to visualize  the same category of data with in different styles without adding the layer twice?

I would like to do something like this
Category=Forest AND Symbology=1 THEN 'Green'
Category=Forest AND Symbology=2 THEN 'Blue'

In QGIS there is a selection "Data defined properties"  with an expression builder, could it be done from it maybe?

**Category Symbology**
Forest    1
Forest  2
Shrub   1
Shrub   2
Grass   1
Grass   2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Rule-based** styling as in the following image, click on the "plus" icon to add more items:

[image: Rule-based styling]

Note the double-quotation marks for Field/Column names and single-quotation marks for strings. Although you don't need double-quotes for Field/Columns, I think it's good practice as it highlights what it is, useful for long logics but this is personal opinion :)

Comment: Just to agree, and to add that if having done this you save the style as a QGIS layer style file you can then access this style file with a text/xml editor... which can make setting up of a complex set of interrelated styles faster than doing it one by one directly in QGIS.

Comment: @user27285, I save style files often but never edited one. But you're right in that it could save a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you! 
That worked perfectly, never thought of rule based styling before, should have looked more carefully =)
Good point about being able to edit the layer style files with an editor.

Comment: The style file is an xml file. In case you aren't familiar with this take a moment to understand a few of the basics about what an xml file looks like (quick Google search) - QGIS uses these a lot, and familiarity with what they look like in general is helpful (the rest you can mostly work out from studying the file produced by QGIS). And try to use a text editor which is advanced enough to support you - one which will tell you if you make a mistake, or which will allow you to fold sections of the file and colour code the text.

Comment: Is it anyone you can recommend? I have used Notepad++ a bit before, but that is also the only one

Comment: @geogrow, I like **Programmer's Notepad** but there's plenty out there and it just depends on personal preference.

Comment: Notepad++ works just fine (it's what I'm using most of the time) - Open the file in Notepad++ / Select menu item: Language | XML / Alt+1 or 2 or 3 (etc) folds(hides) different levels of the xml file / Alt+shift+1 or 2 or 3 unhides these levels. The plugin XML Tools adds further functionality including validating the XML (I don't think you need this plugin for the folding bit, but *I may be wrong* - try and see).